# How do I separate my venv between different projects?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm just learning python coming from Javascript background. In JS I can use npm to manage my dependencies.

For example if I have project1/ and project2/, I can npm init in both of those individual folders, and they wouldn't interrupt with each other.

However, with python if I have project1/ and project2/, and I do

```
python3 -m venv ./venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
```

in project1/ and then say that I install numpy with pip install numpy. Then if I do pip freeze in my project2 folder numpy is also listed as a dependency.

How can I separate them like how I separated them with JS.

Comment: You should not see it in `pip freeze` output if you've activated the venv for `project2`. You can use `pipenv` if you are looking for something that will auto-activate your venv depending on the directory you are in. `pipenv` has its own quirks though, so dyor.

Comment: @Selcuk thank you, pipenv is exactly what I was looking for. Watched this helpful tutorial and got a hang of it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Qmnh5C4Pmo

Answer (score 1):

You can create two different virtual environments for the two projects..
For project1:

```
python3 -m venv ./venv1
source ./venv1/bin/activate
```

For project2:

```
python3 -m venv ./venv2
source ./venv2/bin/activate
```

And both the environments can have different/same packages installed.
For example, let's say you installed `numpy` and `pandas` in `venv1` and `numpy` and `matplotlib` in `venv2`

And the reason peep freeze lists out numpy in your project2 is because you are using the same environment for both the projects, project1 and project2.

Comment: This answer forms a good base, but it doesn't quite get you what you had for JS.  You have to remember to switch between versions when you switch projects.  Nothing is formally tying each virtualenv to a specific project. You have just manual convention you have to follow. I use [PyEnv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) along with a plugin for it that extends it to support virtual environments.  With this setup, you can set it up so that when you are running Python scripts in one project dir, you use one Python version.  When you're in a different project dir, you run a different Python version.